# How do I split a string?

Tags: c#

I have some strings that I want to split.
Each string is built as follows:
Jan (10)
Anna (100)
Etc…
So a name, followed by an empty space and finally a number between brackets.
I want to split this in 2 strings.
String 1 must be only the name and string 2 only the number.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Check out [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `"Jan (10)".Split(' ')` doesn't work? This will split it into the two entries, its then trivial to remove the "(" and ")" from the second result.

Comment: There are _numerous_ (like, over a thousand) questions and answers on Stack Overflow concerning splitting, parsing, and otherwise breaking a string down into desired substrings. Please do some research and attempt _something_. Then if you still have trouble, post a new question that includes [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. If there are over a thousand Q + A concerning splitting. How to find what you want. Anyway ist's only my third day on this site. Is it a good idea to delete my Q, or is this not done? But most of all. Thx everybody for the help. I could resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use split method and send array of chars to split by them.

```
string input = "Jan (10) Anna (100)";
string[] split = input.Split(new[] {' ', ')', '('}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will give you array `Jan , 10 , Anna , 100`

As you can see even indexes are names and the index after that is their number. So get pairs like this. (Note that indexes are 0 based means first one is index 0.)

```
Tuple<string, string>[] pairs = new Tuple<string, string>[split.Length/2];
for (int i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i++)
{
    pairs[i] = new Tuple<string, string>(split[i * 2], split[(i * 2) + 1]); 
}
```

And access them like this.

```
pairs[1].Item1 // will give you second person name
pairs[1].Item2 // will give you second person number
```

Comment: I think you want `pairs[i] = new Tuple<string, string>(split[i * 2], split[(i * 2) + 1]);`

Comment: Thanks. i missed that! @WyattEarp

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Jan (10) Anna (100)";

            string pattern = @"(?'word'\w+)\s\((?'number'\d+)\)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input,pattern);

            foreach(Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["word"].Value + " " + match.Groups["number"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

}
​
```

Comment: This code outputs: *Jan (10)
Anna (100)* (in separate lines) which is not the desired output

Comment: Updated to remove parenthesis.

Comment: The requirement is "String 1 must be only the name and string 2 only the number." This still prints *Jan 10
Anna 100*, name and number on the same line...

Comment: The two string are match.Groups["word"].Value and match.Groups["number"].Value.  I just combined the two into one WriteLine() statement.

Comment: Hi, Thx all for the effort. I tried this, but still no result:
 if (item.ToString().Contains(klant)) {  string tussenstap = (item as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();string patroon = @"(?'word'\w+)\s\((?'number'\d+)\)";    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(tussenstap, patroon);    foreach (Match match in matches)  {
// so here should appear only the name = alleenNaam string alleenNaam = (match.Groups["word"].Value);
and here should come only the number.MessageBox.Show(alleenNaam); string alleenConsumpties = (match.Groups["number"].Value);MessageBox.Show(alleenConsumpties);}

Comment: The ToString() in the code may be giving issues.  ToString() sometimes returns the item type instead of the actual string.  Step through code and see what results you are getting.  Hover over variables with mouse to make sure you are getting the correct results.  The code should work if you are passing a valid string.